# Order by not sorting as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using following query:

```
SELECT plan.datum, plan.anketa, plan.ai as autoinc, plan.objekt as sifra , objekt.sifra, objekt.temp4_da FROM plan 
LEFT JOIN objekt ON plan.objekt = objekt.sifra WHERE objekt.temp4_da = '1'
 AND objekt.sifra >= 30 AND plan.datum > '2019-01-15' and plan.datum < '2019-01-30'
 GROUP BY objekt.sifra
 ORDER BY plan.datum ASC, plan.objekt ASC
```

I get results which is sorted by the last records, though I did put it sorted by date.
[image]

Results should be from 2019-01-15, but as you can see its sorted to last date `plan.datum < '2019-01-30'`...

How can I achive this?

**EDIT:** 
When I select from 2019-01-15 to 2019-01-20 I achive this:
[image]

Comment: Your result seems ok. It seems there is no row from 15 to 20 that pass the query, only from 22 - 29?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach edited. check it out

Comment: The sort results look correct to me (it is sorting by the datum field ascending). But you are misusing the GROUP BY clause which can cause problems.

Comment: @Kickstart yea, seems that group by makes problems here. Thank you.

Comment: is `plan.datum` unique to `plan.object`? I mean has every `plan.object` just one corresponding `plan.datum` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result comes from the ability of MySQL to process incorrect SQL queries with `GROUP BY`. For example, most of the DBMS is not capable to process query like this

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM tab
GROUP BY col1
```

Some DBMS process this query if `col1` is the primary key of `tab`, however, MySQL process it always and it returns a RANDOM `col2` value if there are more than one `col2` values corresponding to `col1`! For example, having table

```
col1 | col2
-----------
a    | 1
a    | 2
```

then MySQL may return `(a, 1)` result on Monday, and `(a, 2)` on Tuesday using my SQL query shown above (I'm little sarcastic).

I believe that is also your case. MySQL picks random `plan.datum` for each `objekt.sifra` (the group by attribute in your query) and you subsequently miss some `plan.datum` values in the result. Fix your query to obtain deterministic values and you will get rid of your problems.

Comment: . . MySQL does not return a "random" row.  It returns values from an *indeterminate* row.  "Random" means something in statistics, and MySQL's choice is definitely not random.  Just undependable.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it does seem to have sorted how you wanted the first 4 rows shows that, those dates are all in the range specified.

You need to just go through basic diagnosis: 
Does 'plan' table actually contain data with those dates?
If it does, then the data is being removed by your query.

So the next easiest to check is the `WHERE`, so remove the other clauses (i.e. leave the 'datum' restrictions), does that data now appear?
If it still doesn't, then the `LEFT JOIN` is the issue, as joins are filters too.

If you do those and the data appears, then the data and your understanding of the data don't match, and you need to check/confirm any assumptions about the data you may have made.

I'm not 100% familiar with mysql, but the `GROUP BY` looks really odd, your not doing any sums, mins, or operations on the group. Do you need that line?